# uploading file to firebase storage and index in realtime DB - no entry in DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have written a function to upload a local file (using cordova `File`) to my firebase storage. It looks like there is no API to iterate all the files in storage (based on other SO threads), so I decided to write the download location to my realtime DB.

At the moment, authentication is *OFF* in my realtime DB and storage for testing. The file is uploaded correctly and I can see it in my storage, but I don't see any DB entry. Can someone help on what is going wrong?

```
 // upload trip data to firebase. currently a public bucket
  cloudUpload(prg) {
    console.log ("cloud upload");
    //this.presentLoader("loading...");
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    console.log ("storage ref is "+storageRef);
    this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file.dataDirectory, this.logFile)
    .then (succ=>{
      console.log ("File read");
      console.log (succ);
      let blob = new Blob([succ],{type:"text/plain"});
      console.log ("Blob  created");
      let name = "file-"+Date()+".txt";
      let uploadUrl = storageRef.child(`tripdata/${name}`);
      let uploadTask = uploadUrl.put(blob); 
      uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        (snapshot) => {
          let progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
          prg.val = progress;

        },
        (error) => {
            console.log ("Firebase put error "+error);
            setTimeout(()=>{prg.val = -1; },500);
            this.presentToast("upload error","error") },
        () => { prg.val = 100;
                setTimeout(()=>{prg.val = -1; },500);
                // write download URL to realtime DB so we can iter it later
                // there is no API in storage today to iterate
                let  downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
                console.log ("Download url is "+downloadURL);
                let key = 'tripDataIndex/'+name;
                console.log ("key="+key);
                 firebase.database().ref(key)
                .set ({'url':downloadURL, 'uploadedon':Date()}); // nothing created
                .catch (err=> {console.log ("ERROR "+err);this.presentToast("error creating index","error")})
                this.presentToast("upload complete")}
      )
    })
    .catch (err=>{console.log ("Cordova Read Error "+err);})
  }
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in an interactive debugger? Do you get to the code that is supposed to write the value to the database?

Comment: Yes it reaches there. Do I need to create TripDataindex as a list first?

Comment: Keys/paths are created in Firebase when you write a value to them and (conversely) removed when you remove the last value from them. Are you sure you have write permission to the location? Is there any message showing on the console? You might also want to catch this potential problem as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/24459/detecting-errors-when-writing-a-value-in-javascript#t=20170724004833276935

Comment: *argh* It seems the problem was in the key value. My "name" was `let name = "file-"+Date()+".txt";` -- `Date()` includes spaces/parenthesis etc -- using a different key name worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was in the key value. My "name" was

```
let name = "file-"+Date()+".txt";
```

`Date()` includes spaces/parenthesis etc, which conflict with the [naming rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)  -- using a different key name worked perfectly!

What is very odd, however, is it did not throw an error. I added a `.catch` at the end like Frank suggested, but it never went to the catch handler.